# How to add an ID using with the class name in multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

For example, we have an HTML tag:

```
<div class="box">This is a box</div>
```

We are using the div tag class name `box` and add an `id="box"` in the same `div` tag. The output is:

```
<div id="box" class="box">This is a box</div>
```

We can achieve the changes with the code below for a single tag:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")["class", "box"].setAttribute("id", "box")
```

But if we don't know or we have multiple classes in the HTML element, how to add `id` to all the tags?

Example:

```
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Output should be like below:

```
<div id="box">Hello World</div>
<div id="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div id="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div id="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: So, you shouldn't be trying to make more the one item have the same `id` - that's going to cause bad things to happen later. Use `id` when there will be one and only one thing with that `id` on the page.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst above code is for an example only in a website we have multiple section using with class name (for example header, slider, about, services, etc..,) I want to add an id using with the class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wild card `*` on class name like below.

```js
$('[class*="box"]').each(function(i, ele) {
  var id = $(this).attr('class');
  $(this).attr('id', id);

});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.box--red {
  background-color: red;
}
.box--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box--green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>

<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>

<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>

<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would do this is a real-world scenario, but it can be acheived by looping over all `div` elements, setting the id to the class name, and then removing the class attribute. I've created a vanilla Javascript example below.

Note: `id` must be unique in the DOM otherwise you may cause multiple issues.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(el) {
  el.id = el.classList;
  el.removeAttribute('class');
});
```

If you need to target different element's that have "box" as the first part of the class attribute you can use the selector `[class^="box"]` in `querySelectorAll` like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="box"]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.id = el.classList;
  el.removeAttribute('class');
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `el.removeAttr()` instead of `el.removeAttribute()`?

Comment: No, `removeAttr()` is a jQuery method while `el.removeAttribute()` is vanilla javascript that doesn't need jQuery

Comment: Although it will work, why are you using the `classList` property if you don't need an array? You're making JavaScript create and array from the string and then convert it back to string to store it in the `id` attribute. Simply use the `className` instead.

Comment: Yes you can use `className` here instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to loop through all the elements so that you can set the attribute *id* with *attr* with the current element's *class*. Then remove the *class* by using *removeClass()*.

```js
$('div[class^=box]').each(function(i, el){
  $(el).attr('id', $(el).attr('class'));
  $(el).removeClass($(el).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
#box{
}
#box--red{
  color:red;
}
#box--blue{
  color:blue;
}
#box--green{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

**Vanilla JavaScript:** Using `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`

```js
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=box]');
elList.forEach(function(el) {
  el.id = el.className;
  el.removeAttribute('class');
});
```

```css
#box{
}
#box--red{
  color:red;
}
#box--blue{
  color:blue;
}
#box--green{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Although it will work, why are you using the `classList` property if you don't need an array? You're making JavaScript create and array from the string and then convert it back to string to store it in the `id` attribute. Simply use the `className` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code would work for you

```js
$("div[class^='box']").each(function() {
  var className = $( this ).attr('class');
  $( this ).attr({id: className}).removeAttr('class');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can do the trick if you are willing to use jQuery:

```js
var boxCollection = $(".wrapper div");
boxCollection.each(function(){
 $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("class"));
});
```

```css
#box-1{
 color: red; 
}
#box-2{
  color: orange;
}
#box-3{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box-3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

I added some color scheme so that its easier to understand the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in JavaScript using the `querySelectorAll()` method and looping through the results:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class^=box]").forEach(function(box) {
  box.setAttribute("id", box.className);
  box.removeAttribute("class");
});
```

```html
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--red">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--blue">Hello World</div>
<div class="box--green">Hello World</div>
```

Note: Although this will work with multi-class tags, spaces are not valid in `id`. Browsers will allow spaces in `id`, but it will be harder to work with them. You can replaces spaces with underscores before assigning them the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is simple and works for the above requirement.

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="box"]');
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  a[i].setAttribute("id",a[i].getAttribute("class"));
  //console.log(a[i].getAttribute("id"));
}
```